# Can VeraCrypt use persistent mount points on Linux?

Tags: bash, mount, encryption, paths, veracrypt

## Can VeraCrypt use persistent mount points on Linux?

### Windows + VeraCrypt + encrypted volume absolute paths

On Windows I can mount veracrypt encrypted partitions/disks *via* batch script which employs ***device name*** displayed by `mountvol.exe`. Such an attribute is highly useful since rebooting can lead to alteration of relative path (`\Device\Harddisk1\Partition3` --> reboot --> `\Device\Harddisk3\Partition3`).

My batch script for veracrypt volumes on Windows (shortened form):

```
@echo
"C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt\VeraCrypt.exe" /v \\?\Volume{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}\ /l z /m label=Encrypted_1 /q
"C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt\VeraCrypt.exe" /v \\?\Volume{yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy}\ /l f /m label=Encrypted_2 /q
[...]
pause
```

### Linux + VeraCrypt + encrypted volume relative paths only?

I have no knowledge about the existence of parallel command to Windows' `/v \\?\Volume{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}\` avaliable for the Linux commandline. I tried (in vain) `--mount=/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` flag, since `mountvol.exe` ***volume name*** is (probably) based on UUID number (imperceptible for `blkid`, though). Official veracrypt/truecrypt documentation allows Linux user to operate only with relative (variable) paths (`/dev/sda3` --> reboot --> `/dev/sdc3`). Due to inconstancy, paths have to be verified each time after the OS is loaded.

My bash script for mounting veracrypt volumes on Linux (shortened form):

```
#! /bin/bash
#
echo "Encrypted_1" && veracrypt --mount /dev/sdq --slot=12 --verbose && echo "Encrypted_1"
echo "Encrypted_2" && veracrypt --mount /dev/sdz3 --slot=1 --verbose && echo "Encrypted_2"
[...]
```

### Solution?

**Does anyone know whether VeraCrypt volume location can be described in absolute terms on Linux?**

If it is not possible, please provide suggestions for achieving the same objective? (eg: `udev`? `fstab`?)

### Erratum

`mountvol.exe` recognizes `GUID`, not `UUID` as was written above.

Answer (score 7):

I have elaborated below answer posted by [David Foerster](https://askubuntu.com/users/175814/david-foerster) and made it more descriptive and clear for other Linux users interested in presented subject.

## Linux + VeraCrypt + encrypted volume absolute paths

According to my research, it seems that assignment of absolute path to VeraCrypt volume is impossible (at least currently) (*vide*: *by-id and by-path* entry on [wiki.archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) under *Persistent block device naming* ([1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming#by-id_and_by-path))).

## Linux + VeraCrypt + semi-persistent block device naming

However, we can use semi-persistent block device naming.

### 1. by-path

`/dev/disk/by-path/` depends on shortest physical path ([2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming#by-id_and_by-path)) and changes as port of controller is switched ([3](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming#by-id_and_by-path)).

To obtain `/dev/disk/by-path/` descriptor, type:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/
```

You can use obtained naming to mount VeraCrypt volume:

```
veracrypt --mount /dev/disk/by-path/[by-path] --slot=6 --verbose
```

`/dev/disk/by-path/[by-path]` can replace relative path in bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
echo "Encrypted_1" && veracrypt --mount /dev/disk/by-path/[by-path1] --slot=12 --verbose && echo "Encrypted_1"
echo "Encrypted_2" && veracrypt --mount /dev/disk/by-path/[by-path2] --slot=1 --verbose && echo "Encrypted_2"
[...]
```

### 2. by-id

`/dev/disk/by-id/` is created according to device serial number ([4](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming#by-id_and_by-path)). [wiki.archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) states that `/dev/disk/by-id/` cannot survive hardware changes i.e. scenario where device is plugged to port of controller subjected to different subsystem ([5](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming#by-id_and_by-path)). [access.redhat.com](https://access.redhat.com/), on the other side, claims that `/dev/disk/by-id/` can be maintained even if device is accessed by different systems ([6](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Online_Storage_Reconfiguration_Guide/persistent_naming.html)). Thus, `symlink` appears to be quite stable in case of `/dev/disk/by-id/` being applied.

To obtain `/dev/disk/by-id/` device naming, type:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/
```

Now, when you have correct one, it can be used to mount VeraCrypt volume:

```
veracrypt --mount /dev/disk/by-id/[id] --slot=6 --verbose
```

Analogously to what was noted in paragraph one, `/dev/disk/by-id/` can be used in bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
echo "Encrypted_1" && veracrypt --mount /dev/disk/by-id/[id1] --slot=12 --verbose && echo "Encrypted_1"
echo "Encrypted_2" && veracrypt --mount /dev/disk/by-id/[id2] --slot=1 --verbose && echo "Encrypted_2"
```

Maybe it will be helpful for someone.

## Addendum

`/dev/disk/by-id/` is not stable enough to forget about correcting mounting script after reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the UUIDs and labels of the file system inside encrypted containers are inaccessible due to encryption and TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt containers don't carry UUIDs or labels on their own (or at least none that udev knows about as opposed to those of LUKS containers).

There's one other sufficiently stable identifier for storage volumes in Linux: **disk IDs**. You can find them in:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/
```

So far I never noticed any dramatic changes to the symbolic links in there, since the names are generated by

- udev, whose basic storage configuration doesn't change often,
- based on the manufacturer name, model name and serial number reported by the drive firmware, which also doesn't change often.

Comment: It works. However, I have to test provided solution against stability. Meanwhile, I have developed your answer into form you can see below. It may turn out that subject is useful for someone else as well.

Comment: `/dev/disk/by-id/` method is too unstable for my taste. After one reboot two symlinks changed. It would be nice if veracrypt used, like dm-crypt, different external and internal UUID.

Comment: Odd. I never had anything change in there that was related to physical drives and started with `ata-*`, `scsi-*`, or even `usb-*` except for 1) the `*-part*` suffixes after changing the partition table or 2) after a release upgrade including major changes to udev. I have unplugged and exchanged drives in the mean time and the kernel names (`sd*`) tend to change every few boots.

Comment: In my case `ata-*` was replaced by `usb-*` for two external HDs made by WD: WDC WD15NMVW-11AV3S3 and WD Elements 107C (1042).

Comment: Is at least one of the prefixes persistent for either of the drives?

Comment: I just plugged a USB drive into the front USB sockets and a USB hub integrated into the display subsequently. They bot result in the same node in `/dev/disk/by-id/`.

Comment: Alternatively you can play around with the udev configuration and create your own symlinks based on a stable device property.

Comment: I deleted former (outdated) `/dev/disk/by-id/` namings. It seems to me that at least one prefix to whole device remained unchanged (maybe whole id). However, *addresses* of partitions were altered. I had `ata-*` and `wwn-*` both pointing to the same partition of this device. No sign of them.

Comment: To play with udev, I have to read documentation first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Before attaching your drive take a ‘snapshot’

```
$> ll /dev/disk/by-id > ~/before.txt
```

Again, after attaching your drive. And look at the diff:

```
$> ll /dev/disk/by-id > ~/after.txt
$> diff ~/before.txt ~/after.txt
```

You should see (i.e. on a two-partion external Samsung drive)

```
> [...] usb-Samsung_M2_Portable_D3F12345678FE094-0:0 -> ../../sdd
> [...] usb-Samsung_M2_Portable_D3F12345678FE094-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdd1
> [...] usb-Samsung_M2_Portable_D3F12345678FE094-0:0-part2 -> ../../sdd2
```

To mount, say partition2 of that to `/mnt/m` (my example: with truecrypt switches)

`veracrypt -t -tc -pPasswordIfYouLike -k "" --protect-hidden=no /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Samsung_M2_Portable_D3F12345678FE094-0:0-part2 /mnt/m`

**You now can reliably use the respective mount script for this drive, no matter to which USB port or in which order respective to other drives it has been attached.**

---

**And for a proper, reliable unmount script:**

`veracrypt -t -d /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Samsung_M2_Portable_D3F12345678FE094-0:0-part2`

---

**stability?**

I am using this first-hand on various docking stations, in various workplaces with several external drives of different brands for months. No problems.